# Delphi - Synchronize cxScheduler with Outlook 2007

Tags: delphi, outlook, ole

I'm usingthe cxScheduler vom DexExpress and want to syncronize it with outlook 2007.
The scheduler offers a method to do this work: cxSchedulerSynchronizeStorageWithOutlook

Problem: When I call this method, I get an EOleSyserror : operation not available.

So I checked the registered type libraries in delphi, and the "Microsoft Outlook 12.0 Object Library" is installed and registered.

So I tried to create an ole object "by hand" :

```
MyOutlook := CreateOLEObject('Outlook.Application');
```

and this work. 
Somebody an idea whats wrong?
Big thx!

Comment: check if this exception is raised when you run the application outside of the delphi IDE.

Comment: Hi RRUZ, you are right - the exception isn't raised when I run the programm outside the IDE. But why?

Comment: this behavior occurs due to OLE. is common in many situations when you interact with these types of objects (OLE) including ADO, Office Via OLE, etc.  the only workaround is disable this kind of exception from the IDE  in Tools-> Options->debugger Options->language exceptions.

Comment: i just found a link with the same problem http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/B138289.aspx

Comment: This post remains listed as unanswered question despite that it's solved by RRUZ. It would be better if the solution is migrated as a new answer post either by @flinkiy1 or RRUZ, wouldn't it?